# How to set character limits in content in ejs template

Tags: node.js, ejs

I am fetching content from Mognodb in EJS template.
I have description field which contains more then 500 characters, but I want to show only 50 Characters in my view.

Can anyone tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the view you can use JavaScript [String.prototype.substring()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
<%= description.substring(0, 50) %>
```

Within MongoDB you can use [$substr](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/substr/) to return a new field with the desired 50 characters:

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([{
    $project: {
        title: 1,
        shortDescription: {
            $substr: ["$description", 0, 50]
        }
    }
}]);
```

Note that in the code example I am using a collection named `collectionName` and fields names like `title` and `description`.. This way will be returned only `title` and `shortDescription` with a limit to 50 characters to use in the view

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was iterating through the keys in the DB so (using the top answer) this is what I did:

> <%= users[i].password.substring(0, 6)+"..."%>

In this case, 'users' is the collection in MongoDB, I'm retrieving the password and only showing 6 characters plus '...' to show that the password is actually longer.

[view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dd1M7.png)

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlUZc.png)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the substring method worked for me in my ejs files. The example below will shrink or truncate characters in the content var to just 20

```
const content = "This is the Home page. iLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Quibusdam doloremque deserunt, exercitationem reiciendis a accusamus? Non illo minima cum modi rem totam fugit animi dolorum."; 
app.get("/",function(req,res){
res.render("home", {
  contentHomeEjs: content.substring(0,20) + "..."
   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<% posts.forEach(function(el){ %>
    <p><%=el.content.substring(0,50) + "..."%></p>
<% });%>
```

Comment: Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.