# Cannot read property 'substring' of undefined in ejs

Tags: javascript, mongodb, ejs

When I try to add new blog posts to my website I am continuously getting this error:

> TypeError: C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\views\home.ejs:15
> 13|
>
> ```
> 14|       <p>
>
> 15|         <%= post.content.substr(0, 100) %>
>
> 16|         <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More</a>
>
> 17|       </p>
>
> 18|       <% })%>
> ```
>
> Cannot read property 'substr' of undefined
> at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12),
> :22:39)
> at Array.forEach ()
> at eval (eval at compile (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:618:12),
> :16:14)
> at returnedFn (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:653:17)
> at tryHandleCache (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:251:36)
> at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:482:10)
> at View.render (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
> at tryRender (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
> at Function.render (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
> at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
> at C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\app.js:35:9
> at C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:16
> at C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:16
> at C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
> at C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4869:21
> at C:\Users\shruti\Desktop\ejs-challenge\node_modules\mongoose\lib\query.js:4397:11

`home.ejs`:

```
<%- include("partials/header") -%>

    <h1>HOME</h1>
    <p> <%= startingContent %> </p>

    <% console.log(posts); %>

    <div class="">
      <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>
      <h1><%= post.title%></h1>

      <p>
        <%= post.content.substr(0, 100) %>
        <a href="/posts/<%=post._id%>">Read More</a>
      </p>
      <% })%>


        <form  action="/compose">
           <button class="btn btn-primary" type="compose" name="button">COMPOSE</button>
        </form>

    </div>


    <%- include("partials/footer") -%>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set character limits in content in ejs template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39094358/how-to-set-character-limits-in-content-in-ejs-template)

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that it *"Cannot read property `'substr'` of `undefined`"*, which means `post.content` is `undefined` inside your `posts.forEach()` loop. Try to log `post` and check its content.

Answer (score 0):

I went through your problem and the easiest solution to that is put brackets between post.content and frame it this way:

```
<%= (post.content).substr(0, 100) %>
```

It is working i tried it myself, Enjoy learning

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Probably there are empty `post.content` values in your database and when the forEach loop retrieves them the function Cannot read property of 'Undefined' meaning empty value. Search through your DB to locate this null/ empty content fields and update or remove them.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this issue you must drop your MongoDB BlogDB table. This issue happens because you have a non-defined variable (post.content) on the very first row/register.

[first empty row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/32Nnk.png)